# APS.NET MVC request routing using query parameter names

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to understand attribute routing in ASP.NET MVC. I understand how routing matches on url elements, but not query parameters.

For example, say I have a rest-style book lookup service that can match on title or ISBN. I want to be able to do something like `GET /book?title=Middlemarch` or `GET /book?isbn=978-3-16-148410-0` to retrieve book details.

How do I specify `[Route]` attributes for this? I can write:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("book/{title}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LookupTitle(string title)
```

but as far as I can tell this also matches `/book/Middlematch` and `/book/978-3-16-148410-0`. If I also have an ISBN lookup endpoint with `[Route("book/{isbn}")]` then the routing engine won't be able to disambiguate the two endpoints.

So how do I distinguish endpoints by query parameter name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `Route()` attribute will meet your requirements:

```cs
[HttpGet] 
// /book?title=Middlemarch 
// /book?isbn=978-3-16-148410-0
// /book?title=Middlemarch&isbn=978-3-16-148410-0 
[Route("book/")] 
public IActionResult LookupTitle(string isbn, string title)
{
    if (isbn != null) { /* TODO */ }
    if (title != null) { /* TODO */ }

    return View();
}
```

When the ASP.NET MVC parser does not find any matching parameters in the route pattern it trying to interpret these as query parameters.

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to permit only one query param to be used (ie either title or isbn but not both) then is there a way to indicate that using the [Route] attribute? Or should I do the obvious and return 400 / bad request if both arguments are non-null?

Comment: @AndyJohnson: If assume that the _title_ will not include `isbn=` fragment and the _isbn_ will not contain `title=` text than it is possible to use `[Route]` attribute with the regular expression constrain to make this work. But I suppose the `LookupTitle()` action method  should be declared with the two parameters, `isbn` and `title`.

Comment: The reference to an article containing an example how to implement [Custom route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-route-constraints) and use it in an attribute.